# memcache fails to start

Tags: php, memcached

I've been following several guides (mainly [this one](http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/installing-memcache-on-windows-for-php/)) on installing memcache on my WAMP stack - but I'm running into a problem which is odd because my work machine had little trouble doing the same.

When I restart Apache I see the following error in the log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/php_memcache.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm running Win7 64-bit, apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.3.10 and have downloaded [php_memcache-2.2.6-5.3-vc9-x86](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) - I've tried the nts version too - but it too fails

memcached *is* installed as a service and currently running

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a copy of `php_memcache.dll` that worked finally. The only difference I can see is that it's a 64-bit version. I'm still unsure as to why this works though. My PHP install is 32-bit, my`PHP_INT_SIZE` is 4

If anyone else runs into this issue and needs the file, I uploaded it to http://www.sendspace.com/file/uq6srb